# Installing Android Auto on Hyundai i30 2013

Tags: hyundai, i30-wagon

I own a Hyundai i30 from 2013 manufacturing in Czech Republic.
I have a multimedia system with gps and maps installed.

I saw online that Hyundai USA released a firmware update for multimedia systems that includes Android Auto inside.

I'm trying to find information on where to download the firmware (as im unable to do it in their website), and to learn wether this update could work on my car model.

Comment: Would a firmware update made to US specs work for your car? Just consider all the other systems...

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!